# Add adjacent inline block to any inline content

Tags: css

My goal is to provide something like a "Read More" link next to a text block. It is automatically added before the content is sent to the client and the block that contains it should be adjacent to the prior text, just as if its part of this text. The problem is that the text block contents are authored using TinyMCE, thus the content will be packed up in a variety of tags (mainly the paragraph tag) - thus the following content will be pushed to the next line (or block).

So before going through the pain of deconstructing the content of the textblock serverside to decide where and how to attach the other block, i thought there might perhaps be a way to get this done using pure CSS. I have a feeling it won't be possible as i think it would require the adjacent block to sort of override properties of the prior block, but then again there might be a thing or two that i missed about all this CSS/inline business.

I created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RnS/)

Thank You for any constructive input on the matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RnS/5/

```
p + p, .adjacentBlock { float : left; }
```

I just floated left the second paragraph and the adjacentBlock. Doing so remember to also apply some kind of float clearing to the parent container (the `<div>` in your example)

Comment: Interesting! Thx! I will try to apply this and let you know. In any case, i never saw the p + p definition (or any + definition of such kind) before. What does it mean?

Comment: it's the adjacent sibling selector: in that case it matches all `p` soon preceded by another `p` - so, in your example, it will work until you markup is not changed (with another adjacent `p`)

Answer (score 1):

You may use use pseudo-elements in css, by adding an ID to your previous tag:

```
#block:after {
    content:"You will have this appended.";
}
```

You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RnS/14/